# Reloading rails view from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose I have the following view in my rails app

```
<% if is_subscriber? %>
<%= render :partial => 'subscriber_page' %>
<% else %>
<%= render :partial => 'payment_form' %>
<% end %>
```

The payment form submits a post-rquest to the controller show page. In my routes file I have:

```
  match ':users(/:id)', :to => 'users#submit_payment', :via => :post
```

My submit payment helper method is:

```
def submit_payment
    current_user.is_subscriber = true
    show
end
```

However when I run this I get a `submit_payment` template missing error. How can I make sure that the users show page is simply reloaded when the helper method is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to redirect to the show page. Try this:

```
redirect_to user_path(@user) # Note you need to send the show page an :id param
```

If you're just wanting to render a specific partial, do this:

```
render :partial => 'show'
```

However, if you want something more seamless, like submitting the form VIA Ajax, which gets back a partial and then on success dumps it in to a waiting DIV or something, you can do that as well, though with a bit more complexity.

Comment: Yep, I am. The only problem I have is that the template logic for the show page still gets rendered as if `@user.is_subscriber = false`